# How to configure VSCode to find a third-party tool (e.g. stack, yamllint) if these tools are installed through anaconda?

Tags: visual-studio-code, path-variables

Assuming that VSCode is installed and an anaconda environment is setup. The default conda environment contains language analysis and compilation tools like stack (for haskell) and yamllint (for yaml). However, since conda 3.4 they are under <conda_install_dir>/bin, which is not included in system PATH environment variables. The only executable is conda itself.

After installation of VSCode and its plugin, I frequently encounter error messages indicating that executables of these tools are not found. E.g. for stack, the message is:

```
Project requires Cabal but it isn't installed
```

It appears that the only way to make it work is to override the PATH variable in VSCode to make it different from the one used by OS. Is there a option to allow this overriding?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

have you tried updating your PATH to simply include it  ?

Comment: That will mess up my other environment, including most CLIs. Conda used to do this, but after version 4.5, now the PATH only include condabin dir (which only has the conda command)

Comment: Search msdn on "set compiler and build properties". It's configurable per project it's possible to include extra directories

Comment: alternatively you might startup vscode with a batch file setting the path var in there (and restore it afterwards), if it ONLY works with path.
Or read this article https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: I thought MSDN is for visual studio, not VSCode? I'm not even running windows

Comment: I don't think overriding PATH and setting it back is a scalable solution. The link you provided only applies to python executable, not other tools installed through conda, some of which are not even written in python (stack in haskell is a good example).

Conda is a general-purpose dependency manager, this is still one of its applications

Comment: Well Its been a while that i 've been in that sistuation, eventually i just made a "good" conda environment, containing all libs i used in all my projects. but you have to be sure they dont bite eachother. (which to me was a opencv nightmare)